# Counting number occurrences of certain words in entire CSV file as well as per row in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, dataset, counter

I am processing data from a number of servers and producing a CSV file for each server. I have managed to compile data from all the servers in a single file and consolidated file has data as per below-

```
Description,dc1pp1sellv01,dc1pp2sellv01,dc2pp1sellv01
1.1 Database Placement,PASSED,PASSED,PASSED
1.2 Use dedicated least privilaged account,PASSED,PASSED,PASSED
1.3 Diable MySQL history,PASSED,PASSED,FAILED
2.1 Ensure old passwords is set to 1,PASSED,DEPRICATED,NA
```

Each server column in the above file can have result value, either of the below-

["PASSED","FAILED","EXCEPTION","NA","DEPRECATED"]

From the above CSV file, I want to count the result and create a dataset that looks like below

```
Description,dc1pp1sellv01,dc1pp2sellv01,dc2pp1sellv01,PASSED,FAILED,EXCEPTION,NA,DEPRECATED
1.1 Database Placement,PASSED,PASSED,PASSED,3,0,0,0,0
1.2 Use dedicated least privilaged account,PASSED,PASSED,PASSED,3,0,0,0,0
1.3 Diable MySQL history,PASSED,PASSED,FAILED,2,1,0,0,0
2.1 Ensure old passwords is set to 1,PASSED,DEPRICATED,NA,1,0,0,1,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proposal (rather verbose to highlight what's going on):

```
import csv

events = ["PASSED", "FAILED", "EXCEPTION", "NA", "DEPRECATED"]

# Open files
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv_in, open('data_out.csv', 'w') as csv_out:

    # Initialize csv-reader and -writer
    csv_reader, csv_writer = csv.reader(csv_in), csv.writer(csv_out)

    # Process header
    line_in = next(csv_reader)
    line_out = line_in + events
    csv_writer.writerow(line_out)

    # Process data
    for line_in in csv_reader:
        line_out = line_in
        for event in events:
            line_out += [sum(1 if event == entry else 0
                         for entry in line_in[1:])]
        csv_writer.writerow(line_out)
```

I'm assuming your data are in a file named `data.csv`. You have to adjust that. I hope it works ...

PS: There's a misspelling in your sample data: `DEPRICATED` should be `DEPRECATED`. This leads to a non-expected output.

A more compact version without the unnecessary auxiliary variables would look like:

```
import csv

events = ["PASSED", "FAILED", "EXCEPTION", "NA", "DEPRECATED"]
with open('data.csv', 'r') as fin, open('data_out.csv', 'w') as fout:
    in_, out = csv.reader(fin), csv.writer(fout)
    out.writerow(next(in_) + events)
    out.writerows(line + [sum(1 if event == entry else 0 for entry in line[1:])
                          for event in events]
                  for line in in_)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count occurrences of particular words. Assuming you already opened the `.csv` file and stored in the string `input` : you can do :

```
from collections import Counter

res_values = ("PASSED", "FAILED", "EXCEPTION", "NA", "DEPRECATED")

input = ("Description,dc1pp1sellv01,dc1pp2sellv01,dc2pp1sellv01\n"
         "1.1 Database Placement,PASSED,PASSED,PASSED\n"
         "1.2 Use dedicated least privilaged account,PASSED,PASSED,PASSED\n"
         "1.3 Diable MySQL history,PASSED,PASSED,FAILED\n"
         "2.1 Ensure old passwords is set to 1,PASSED,DEPRICATED,NA")

print('\n'.join(
    [line + ',' + ','.join(
        [str(Counter(line.split(','))[res])
         if i != 0
         else res
         for res in res_values]
    )
     for i, line in enumerate(input.split('\n'))]))
```

I used list comprehensions to a better optimization of the process (as the files may be very large), but here's another clearer code that does exactly the same thing :

```
split = input.split('\n')                      # Split the input line by line
for i, line in enumerate(split):               # For each line of the input
    if i == 0:                                 # Write full result name (for the first line)
        split[i] += ',' + ','.join(res_values)
    else:                                      # Count and write result occurrences
        counts = Counter(line.split(','))
        for res in res_values:
            split[i] += ',' + str(counts[res])
print('\n'.join(split))                        # Join the full string
```

I've proposed a ready-to-execute solution, but for optimization purposes, it is of course better reading a file line by line than storing it in a string variable like here.